# What is partimento?

Tags: theory, terminology

Could not find a good explanation of what partimento is. I would like to know more. I only found you tube compositions. I understand it has something to do with counterpoint?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partimento

Comment: Yes could not understand it was more a description of something vague...

Comment: The point of starting at the wiki page is to follow the links!  Take the time to follow, for example, the link to figured bass.

Comment: thanks, Carl. I did, never mind. I will figure it out. but just adding a personal comment (not personally for you carl) :  I thought people offer help and explanations in this site. i, for example, had difficulty understanding. lots of questions here have answers in Wikipedia and still, people look here if they did not understand...

Comment: @LoveIsHere this site is great for getting clarification on obscure topics, but it helps to ask very specific question. This question is probably too broad.

Comment: @Peter thanks I understand but as you can see the answer I got from Laurence was finally made maybe a broad concept  clear but in a way i can explore it more which i could not before because i did not understand what i am looking at :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partimento was a system of teaching harmony - both written and improvised - based on providing a bass line (which might or might not include 'figured bass' numbers).  'Harmonise this bass line' rather than 'Harmonise this melody'.